# Getis-Ord GI and Moran's I when interested in clustering of data values not points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, clustering, autocorrelation

I have a dataset with many clustered (often coincident) points, each of which contains data.

I am not interested in the fact that the points are obviously clustered.  I would like to know whether the data values are clustered.

My reading of [this page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p00000011000000) is that it is appropriate to run the Getis Ord GI tool on the point dataset directly.  Similarly Global Moran's I.

Is this correct?

Comment: I think you are correct. I believe it's as simple as choosing your field of interest as your input field.